# Communicate between two machines without a switch

Tags: ssh, networking, ethernet

Given:

- Ubuntu laptop with dynamic ip.
- Raspberry pi headless with static ip.
- A single Ethernet cable (can be normal or crossover).

How can I ssh into the Pi from the laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have (at least) a couple of choices

1. Run a DHCP server on your Pi. This will assign addresses to clients that connect to it. (Even if there's only one client - your laptop.) As an example this could be `dnsmasq` or `udhcpd`.
2. Assuming your Pi has an address `192.168.1.1` with a typical 24 bit subnet you add an address from that subnet to the laptop's ethernet interface:

   ```
   ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0
   ```

Either of these operations should give you network connectivity between the two systems. Having done that, you need to [ensure your Pi is actually running an ssh server](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) by enabling it in `raspi-config`.

Comment: Thanks roaima.  Had some strange `enp0s25` interface instead of `eth0`.  Did your number 2 solution, restarted network,and worked perfect.

Comment: @user1032531 you wouldn't have needed to restart the network.